# Find the ratio between two file sizes as a percentage

Tags: python, filesize

I've written a short Python script to find the original and minified sizes of a script, by comparing file sizes, and to find the difference and compression ratio. The script itself follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import os
import sys

file1 = sys.argv[1]
file2 = sys.argv[2]

file1Size = os.stat(file1).st_size
file2Size = os.stat(file2).st_size

difference = file1Size - file2Size

ratio = (((file1Size - file2Size) / file1Size) * 100) # Math to find ratio. Somehow broken (?!).

print("Original size: " + str(file1Size))
print("New size: " + str(file2Size))
print("Change in size: " + str(difference))
print("Size change ratio: " + str(ratio) + "%")
```

However, when I run this script, it outputs:

```
Original size: 2975
New size: 1125
Change in size: 1850
Size change ratio: 0%
```

P.S. When I input the formula (`(((file1Size - file2Size) / file1Size) * 100)`) manually into a calculator, it returns the correct result, only adding to my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those sizes are integers, so Python is performing integer division. Try converting the sizes to floats first:

```
file1Size = float(os.stat(file1).st_size)
file2Size = float(os.stat(file2).st_size)
```

In integer division, `1 / 2` is 0. But with floating pointer numbers, `1.0 / 2.0` will be 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 2.x try:

```
from __future__ import division
```

In Python 2.x standard "/" is integer division